# Reading CSV values and showing them in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a project going on and this is the first time I've encountered CSV. I've read numerous post but haven't found what I need.

So we have and CSV with values like this

```
Name,Country,Color,Pet
David,UK,Red,Dog
Andy,USA,Blue,Cat,Dog,Fish
...
```

So sometimes there are multiple values on "Pet", and that's how clients software outputs CSV and we can't change it.
I am looking for solution on how to combine columns after nth column. So for an example, after 6th column I need ti combine all columns in row to 7th.

Is that possible to achieve?

I would paste the code I'm working on but it's sample I've found online using fgetcsv function and outputing table.

Also, is it possible to read rows instead of columns like it renders it?

Anyone who helps out will do HUGE favor!

Answer (score 0):

Not too hard really...

```
$csvdata = file_get_contents($filepath);
$lines = explode("\n", $csvdata); // split data by new lines
foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {
    $values = explode(',', $line); // split lines by commas
    // set values removing them as we ago
    $linevalues[$i]['name'] = trim($values[0]); unset($values[0]);
    $linevalues[$i]['country'] = trim($values[1]); unset($values[1]);
    $linevalues[$i]['color'] = trim($values[2]); unset($values[2]);
    // assign remaining columns (array)
    $linevalues[$i]['pet'] = array_values($values); 
}
print_r($linevalues); // see the result
```

Comment: `array_shift()` would make this much cleaner, I feel. Also, there's an s missing in `unset($value[2]);`.

Comment: @janh cleaner yes but not clearer, just trying to keep code in answers more understandable for any newcomers by being step by step, makes it easier to modify if needs change. fixed the typo tho cheers.

Comment: CSV has escaping, you should use the existing PHP APIs to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `php-parsecsv` library.

If you deal with multiple values in one cell (eg "`Red;Green;Blue`"), separated by some char and you need to convert this cell value to array - take a look at:
https://packagist.org/packages/decss/item-parser